# Conditional Doc Type for Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, doctype

I have an issue with my application as it's working on IE 8 and IE 11, as few of my customers are using IE8 and few are using IE 11. I am getting some layout related issues which are coming because of doctype tag.

When I add this doctype tag in my master page my layout distorted in IE 8, but works fine with IE 11

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Similarly when I remove this tag it works fine for IE 8 but not in IE 11.

Comment: So you're saying that the page looks OK in quirksmode but not in standards mode? If so, something is really wrong in the code.

Anyhow: Do you have anything above the <!DOCTYPE> declaration? Line breaks? Comments? <!-- comment -->

Comment: You can consider it to be like this but, in one browser it looks fine and in other browser it's not.. So is there anyway to make the doctype conditional?

Comment: Well, the fact is that IE8 is a bit more delicate when it comes to whitespace before the <!DOCTYPE> then—for instance—IE11. That's why I'm assuming that there is something in your code prior to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, check the mode that the browsers are using to show the page. All versions of IE from IE8 come with a dev tools window that can be opened by pressing F12. This will show you what mode the browser is using. If it's anything other than "IE8 Standards" (for IE8) or "Edge" (for IE11) then you need to ask yourself why.

Knowing what mode the browser is in will help you a lot in deciphering the problem.

Regarding the doctype, there is only one rule here: always always **always** include a doctype. You should not be writing HTML pages on today's web that don't have a doctype at all.

If you don't have a doctype, then IE (all versions, and other browsers too) will put the page into "Quirks mode". This will cause issues with your page layout, and will cause it to work differently across different browsers (even across different versions of the same browser). Quirks mode should be avoided wherever possible, and thus you should always have a doctype.

If you have a choice of which doctype to use, consider using the HTML5 doctype: `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

In theory, pretty much any (valid) doctype you use should work the same: ie to put the page into standards mode. The doctype you're using is the XHTML Transitional doctype. This should be fine, but equally the HTML5 doctype should also work fine too, and the simpler doctype string lowers the possibility of a typo making it invalid and breaking the page.

The doctype must be the very first thing on the page. No comments or white space before it. This can cause some versions of IE to see the doctype as invalid.

With a valid doctype in place, you should no longer be getting Quirks mode showing as the mode in the dev tools.

The next thing to do is run your HTML code through the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/). This will return details of any HTML syntax errors you may have in your code. Errors that show up here are often the kinds of things that cause cross-browser weirdness, so you should fix anything that is reported in the validator.

If IE's browser mode is showing as Compatibility mode, there are a number of reasons why this could happen, but you can generally deal with that by making sure your HTML `<head>` contains the following line:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

The 'edge' setting tells all versions of IE to use their best available rendering mode. You should never need to use any other value for this flag unless you have a very specific reason to use a particular compatibility mode.

For further reading, I've [written a detailed article](http://spudley.com/blog/keeping-ie-in-standards-mode) explaining how to keep IE in standards mode and why that's a good thing.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put X-UA-Compatible meta tag on `<head>`. It will make IE render html with the lastest layout engine.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

Comment: I already had a tag <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9,IE=IE7,IE=IE8"> and I changed it to the tag you mentioned. But, no luck..